# When did Jackson decide not to be the town selectman in Gilmore Girls?

Tags: gilmore-girls

In Gilmore Girls, when Jacskon decided to run for town selectman against Taylor Doose, he wins with a major difference. Even though he shows reluctancy from the beginning, I don't remember seeing a formal scene where he gives up the job back to Taylor. Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Happened a couple of times on GG: story-lines that were abandoned, even though they could have easily been resolved in a single scene (e.g. Jackson handing back power to Doose, Rory giving up her job at the Stamford Gazette,...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BCdotWeb mentioned, it is an [Aborted Arc](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AbortedArc):

> When a Story Arc disappears off the face of the storyline without warning, never to be heard from again.

> For a long while viewers will likely be under the impression that the disappeared major Plot Point will pop up any minute now — an impression which will eventually give way to a dawning comprehension that the story has moved on, none of the factors that made this plot point important matter any more and it would be just ridiculous for someone to suddenly recall the whole thing now, after all this time.

In the *Gilmore Girls* there are a few of those:

- Season two episode Hammers and Veils has Rory obsess about charity work she can do to make her more interesting to Harvard, but it never comes up again and her doing charity work is never a plot point again.
- In season two, Taylor buys the locale next to Luke's diner to sell decorative plates, but that never comes up again and the next time we hear about that shop he wants to sell candy out of it.
- One of the most notable was the lawsuit Jason brought up against the Gilmores. It was a major development in the plot, but once it served its purpose of breaking Lorelai and Jason up, it was never mentioned again.
- Jackson being voted Town Selectman, ousting Taylor. He campaigned hard and managed to win the election, then immediately regretted it. It gets mentioned maybe twice more, then Taylor's back to the job with absolutely no warning.
- Rory getting a job at the Stamford Eagle Gazette right before going back to Yale. This is never mentioned again.

But if we'd like to somehow put it on a timeline, it would have to happen sometime between the end of season 5 and the beginning of season 6